# Nodejs: content encoding error

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

I have the following Node.js code:

```
var net = require('net');
var sys=require('sys');

var reqHash={};
var resHash={};

var server = net.createServer( function(soc){

  soc.on('data', function(data){
    //sys.puts(data);
    var requestData=data;

    var conn = net.Socket();
    conn.connect(80,"www.xlhi.com",function(){
       conn.write(data);
    });
    conn.on("connect",function(){
       //sys.puts("connected");
    });
    conn.on("data",function(x){
      var responseData=x.toString();
      //sys.puts(responseData);
      var f=50;
      var toTransmit="";

      if(responseData!=undefined){
        var N=responseData.length;
        if(N>f){
          var p=Math.floor(N/f);
          var p_rem=N%f;

          var hash="";
          var chunk="";
          for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
            chunk=responseData.substr(f*i,f);
            hash=DJBHash(chunk);
            toTransmit+=chunk;
            if(hash<0){
              hash=hash*-1;
            }
            if(resHash[hash]!=undefined){
              //sys.puts("***Hit"+resHash[hash]);
              //toTransmit=toTransmit+"***EOH"+hash+"EOH***";
            }else{
              resHash[hash]=chunk;
              //toTransmit+=chunk;
            }
          }
          //remainder:
          //toTransmit+="***";
          //sys.puts(f*p+" "+p_rem);
          chunk=responseData.substr(f*p);
          //sys.puts("EOH"+chunk+"\n");
          hash=DJBHash(chunk);
          toTransmit+=chunk;
        }else{
           toTransmit=responseData;
        }
        //sys.puts(x.toString().substr(0,50));
        //sys.puts(toTransmit.substr(0,50));
        sys.puts(toTransmit);
        sys.puts(x);
        soc.write(toTransmit);   /*This line causes content encoding error!*/
      }
    });
  });
});

server.on('error', function (err){
  // Error processing i just pass whole object
  console.log(err);
});

server.listen(8080,"172.16.1.218");
console.log('Server is listening %d\n', 8080);


function DJBHash(str) {
  var hash = 5381;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charCodeAt(i)) & 0xffffffff;
  }
  return hash;
}
```

Specifically, I'm having trouble with the line marked above. When I change `soc.write(toTransmit);` to `soc.write(x)`, everything works fine and I don't get any content encoding errors when I hit refresh in my browser.

As you can see, toTransmit is a chunked version of `responseData=x.toString();`. I'm guessing I need some way of converting toTransmit into a format suitable for writing to the socket. I don't know how to do this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I'm using v0.4.10

Comment: I've figured it out now... soc.write(new Buffer(toTransmit))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation : http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#response.write

`response.write` takes string or buffer. If it is a string, it also takes an encoding, the default encoding is `utf-8`.

So the encoding problems comes from the fact that you give him a string in UTF-8 and your browser is set in to another encoding.

In this code you also don't write any header, the browser must guess if it is `text/plain` or `text/html` you are sending him.