# Nodejs: convert string to buffer

Tags: javascript, string, encoding, node.js

I'm trying to write a string to a socket (socket is called "response"). Here is the code I have sofar (I'm trying to implement a byte caching proxy...):

```
var http = require('http');
var sys=require('sys');

var localHash={};

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var proxy = http.createClient(80, request.headers['host'])
    var proxy_request = proxy.request(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
    proxy_request.addListener('response', function (proxy_response) {
    proxy_response.addListener('data', function(x) {
        var responseData=x.toString();
        var f=50;
        var toTransmit="";
        var p=0;        

        var N=responseData.length;
        if(N>f){
            p=Math.floor(N/f);

            var hash="";
            var chunk="";
            for(var i=0;i<p;i++){
                chunk=responseData.substr(f*i,f);
                hash=DJBHash(chunk);
                if(localHash[hash]==undefined){
                    localHash[hash]=chunk;
                    toTransmit=toTransmit+chunk;
                }else{
                    sys.puts("***hit"+chunk);
                    toTransmit=toTransmit+chunk;//"***EOH"+hash;
                }
            }
            //remainder:
            chunk=responseData.substr(f*p);
            hash=DJBHash(chunk);
            if(localHash[hash]==undefined){
                localHash[hash]=chunk;
                toTransmit=toTransmit+chunk;
            }else{
                toTransmit=toTransmit+chunk;//"***EOH"+hash;
            }
        }else{
            toTransmit=responseData;
        }
        response.write(new Buffer(toTransmit));   /*error occurs here */
    });
    proxy_response.addListener('end', function() {
        response.end();
    });
    response.writeHead(proxy_response.statusCode, proxy_response.headers);
    });
    request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
        sys.puts(chunk);
        proxy_request.write(chunk, 'binary');
    });
    request.addListener('end', function() {
        proxy_request.end();
    });
}).listen(8080);



function DJBHash(str) {
    var hash = 5381;
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + str.charCodeAt(i)) & 0xffffffff;
    }
    if(hash<-1){
        hash=hash*-1;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

The trouble is, I keep getting a "content encoding error" in Firefox. It's as if the gizipped content isn't being transmitted properly. I've ensured that "toTransmit" is the same as "x" via console.log(x) and console.log(toTransmit).

It's worth noting that if I replace `response.write(new Buffer(toTransmit))` with simply `response.write(x)`, the proxy works as expected, but I need to do some payload analysis and then pass "toTransmit", not "x".

I've also tried to `response.write(toTransmit)` (i.e. without the conversion to buffer) and I keep getting the same content encoding error.

I'm really stuck. I thought I had this problem fixed by converting the string to a buffer as per another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090510/nodejs-content-encoding-error), but I've re-opened a new thread to discuss this new problem I'm experiencing.

I should add that if I open a page via the proxy in Opera, I get gobblydeegook - it's as if the gzipped data gets corrupted.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Buffer.byteLength

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without digging very deep into your code, it seems to me that you might want to change

```
var responseData=x.toString();
```

to

```
var responseData=x.toString("binary");
```

and finally

```
response.write(new Buffer(toTransmit, "binary"));
```

Comment: "binary" encoding is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @Andris: Legend, here's what I did: `var responseData=x.toString("binary");` and `response.write(toTransmit,"binary");` It's all working now! Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: @Eamorr, seriously, don't do that! The "binary" encoding is deprecated and will get removed from node! I cite the docs: "'binary' - A way of encoding raw binary data into strings by using only the first 8 bits of each character. This encoding method is deprecated and should be avoided in favor of Buffer objects where possible. This encoding will be removed in future versions of Node."

Comment: @Eamorr, could you update your original post with the code you're using now?

Comment: I agree that binary encoding is generally a really bad idea. But it has been "deprecated" since node.js 0.1.100 and still available in v0.5 and a lot of important modules like the MongoDB driver (node-mongodb-native) use it in some extent.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked for me with a 3rd party library called snappy

Comment: Ok, so if binary is deprecated, how do you do it the other way?

Comment: 'binary' has been available for several years by now and it seems it is not going anywhere. Even several node.js core apis return 'binary' by default.

Answer (score 43):

How about this?

```
var responseData = Buffer.from(x, 'utf8');
```

from: [Convert string to buffer Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436824/convert-string-to-buffer-node)

Comment: This is the right way to do it without deprecated functions

Answer (score 5):

[From the docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffers.html#buffers):

> Pure Javascript is Unicode friendly but not nice to binary data. When
>   dealing with TCP streams or the file system, it's necessary to handle
>   octet streams. Node has several strategies for manipulating, creating,
>   and consuming octet streams.
>
> Raw data is stored in instances of the Buffer class. A Buffer is
>   similar to an array of integers but corresponds to a raw memory
>   allocation outside the V8 heap. A Buffer cannot be resized.

So, don't use strings for handling binary data.

Change `proxy_request.write(chunk, 'binary');` to `proxy_request.write(chunk);`.

Omit `var responseData=x.toString();`, that's a bad idea.

Instead of doing `substr` on a string, use `slice` on a buffer.

Instead of doing `+` with strings, use the "concat" method from the [buffertools](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-buffertools).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, now new Buffer() is deprecated since Node.js v10+, so instead of new Buffer() better to use Buffer.from(you_string,enecoding_format)
Change this

```
 response.write(new Buffer(toTransmit));
```

to this:

```
 response.write(Buffer.from(toTransmit,'binary'));
```