# What is the NodeJs equivalent to Java getBytes()

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I need to perform a Java function in NodeJs.

```
string.getBytes()
```

In Java, this translates a string to a byte array [`byte[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Maybe the iconv module can help? What encoding do you need? Unicode-based things are probably not too difficult (you can get the codepoints with string.codePointAt() ) ?

Comment: Since many proficient Javascript/nodejs developers may not know Java, perhaps you could describe what `getBytes()` does so more of us might know what nodejs features could be a substitute.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226189/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytearray

Comment: And also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094615/nodejs-convert-string-to-buffer

Comment: @jfriend00 In Java, this translates a string to a byte array byte[].

Comment: Why not use Buffer?, e.g. var b = new Buffer(str);

Answer (score 5):

@Eranga Kapukotuwa I don't know if you still need an answer for this question but I have used the below code to get this work done in one of my projects and it works perfect.

```
var getBytes = function (string) {
var utf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
    arr.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
}

console.log('Array ', arr);

return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the same

```
Class Method: Buffer.byteLength(string[, encoding])#
```

- string String
- encoding String, Optional, Default: 'utf8'
- Return: Number

  ```
  Buffer.byteLength(str, 'utf8')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
> s = 'あhello'
'あhello'
> s.split('').forEach(function(c,i) { console.log(s.charCodeAt(i) + " " + c); });
12354 あ
104 h
101 e
108 l
108 l
111 o
undefined

// Or as one line
s.split('').map(function(c,i) { return s.charCodeAt(i) }).reduce(function(a, b) {return a.toString(16) + " " + b.toString(16)})
```

Comment: a = []; s.split('').map(function(c,i) { a.push(s.charCodeAt(i)) }); a // might help more

Comment: That's not really a byte array, though. It is an integer array (with values bigger than 255, as you show).