# Convert string to buffer Node

Tags: node.js

I am using a library which on call of a function returns the toString of a buffer.

The exact code is

```
return Buffer.concat(stdOut).toString('utf-8');
```

But I don't want string version of it.

I just want the buffer

So how to convert string back to buffer.

Something like if

```
var bufStr = Buffer.concat(stdOut).toString('utf-8');
//convert bufStr back to only Buffer.concat(stdOut).
```

How to do this?

I tried doing

```
var buf = Buffer.from(bufStr, 'utf-8');
```

But it throws utf-8 is not a function.
When I do

```
var buf = Buffer.from(bufStr);
```

It throws TypeError : this is not a typed array.

Thanks

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can do:

```
var buf = Buffer.from(bufStr, 'utf8');
```

But this is a bit silly, so another suggestion would be to copy the minimal amount of code out of the called function to allow yourself access to the original buffer.  This might be quite easy or fairly difficult depending on the details of that library.

Comment: I tried to do `Buffer.from(bufStr, 'utf-8');` but it says utf-8 is not a function. 
If I omit the second argument utf-8 then it throws TypeError: this is not a typed array.

Comment: @Aniket: Probably your Node version is older.  Try just `Buffer(bufStr)` instead until you upgrade.

Comment: Actually, it should be 'utf8' and not 'utf-8'. Edited the answer.

Comment: `iconv-lite` is better, because it uses standard charset names from world of client js (like `utf-8`), instread of NodeJS redefinitions (like `utf8`).

Comment: `Buffer.from(str)` is enough, as 'utf8' is default. https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding

Comment: `utf8` is the default, so could be skipped without any effect. But for readability, i would still keep it while not everyone knows the default value.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `Buffer.from()` to convert a string to buffer. More information on this can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_str_encoding)

```
var buf = Buffer.from('some string', 'encoding');
```

for example

```
var buf = Buffer.from(bStr, 'utf-8');
```

Answer (score 16):

**Note:** Just reposting John Zwinck's comment as answer.

One issue might be that you are using a older version of Node (for the moment, I cannot upgrade, codebase struck with `v4.3.1`). Simple solution here is, using the deprecated way:

```
new Buffer(bufferStr)
```

**Note #2:** This is for people struck in older version, for whom `Buffer.from` does not work

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me, you might change your code like this

```
var responseData=x.toString();
```

to

```
var responseData=x.toString("binary");
```

and finally

```
response.write(new Buffer(toTransmit, "binary"));
```

Comment: Amazing I was looking for this only!

Comment: Where does toTransmit come from? This is seemingly randomly in your answer without context.