# How to loop over an array and write each iteration to the same file [nodejs]

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have an array of data which i want to loop over and while looping over I want to write them to the same file. How i can achieve the same, my following code will only print the last iteration.

```
for (j = 0; j < arrayPart.length; j++){
    fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', arrayPart[j])
}
```

`message.txt` will have the last value of `arrayPart`.

Comment: `writeFile` overwrites the file every time you call it. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), specifically "writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `join` the array and write to the file once:

```
fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', arrayPart.join(""));
```

Comment: Yes it worked!, now i have one more question, the arrayPart array has a size of 600bytes. but i need only 200 bytes of it, How can i mention the size , while looping that it should just write 200 bytes

Comment: @NidhiSharma `arrayPart.join("")` will result in a string. If you want to write only the first 200 character of that string, you could slice it like `fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', arrayPart.join("").slice(0, 200));`

Comment: @NidhiSharma in case the string contains some multi-byte characters, and you want exactly 200 bytes, then just [transform it into a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37436824/9867451) first then slice that buffer: `fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', Buffer.from(arrayPart.join(""), "utf8").slice(0, 200));`

Comment: Ok, got it.  But arrayPart is an array of responses that we get from couple of URL's, In some cases we might want to write the image (like sample.jpg). will this help me in writing it to image files also

Comment: @NidhiSharma I'm not sure. If the array contains buffers instead of strings, then `join` won't work as expected, you might want to use `Buffer.concat` for that: `fs.writeFileSync('sample.jpg', Buffer.concat(arrayPart))`. `Buffer.concat` returns a buffer, so you can use `slice` on it like before.

Comment: When i use this I get the following error:
(node:76229) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "list[0]" argument must be one of type Array, Buffer, or Uint8Array. Received type string
(node:76229) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: @NidhiSharma `Buffer.concat` should only be called on an array of buffers. If the array has strings in it, you should use `join`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181912/discussion-between-nidhi-sharma-and-ibrahim-mahrir).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of opening/writing/closing at every iteration I would open a write stream, write inside the loop and close at the end:

```
 const message = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "./message.txt");
 for (let j = 0; j <arrayPart.length; j++){
      message.write(arrayPart[j]);
 }
 message.close();
```

Or you just join the array and write all at once:

```
 fs.writeFileSync('message.txt', arrayPart.join(""));
```

Comment: Yes it worked!, now i have one more question, the arrayPart array has a size of 600bytes. but i need only 200 bytes of it, How can i mention the size , while looping that it should just write 200 bytes.

Comment: @nidhi whats inside the array?

Comment: arrayPart is an array of responses which we get from hitting couple of URL's, I have stored all the responses in an array(name is arrayPart). Now i am looping over arrayPart and writing it to file. Since I want the file to be particular size. also can i use the same thing if file is not '.txt' but '.jpg'