# how to convert string that contains Base64 code of a image to Byte?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm trying to save image in mongoose and my client convert that image to Base64 string and send it to server and i want to save that string to byte 
because that string size is larger than image and i want to improve my performance

this is my Heroes collection

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Heroes = mongoose.model('Heroes',{
    Name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true 
    },
    Heroes_Image:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = {Heroes};
```

and this is my server side:

```
var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Heroes} = require('./models/Heroes');
var net = require('net');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var clients = [];
net.createServer(function (socket) {
    // Identify this client
    socket.name = socket.remotePort 

    // Put this new client in the list
    clients.push(socket);

    console.log(socket.name + " joined the chat");

    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        var j = JSON.parse(data);
        db.collection('Heroes').insertOne({
            Name: j.Name,
            Heroes_Image: j.Heroes_Image
        });// here save Base64 string of client image and it waste memory
    })
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs: convert string to buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094615/nodejs-convert-string-to-buffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Blob](https://www.javascripture.com/Blob) to save it as a file.